# Can Blender be used to design 2D clothing patterns?

Tags: cloth-simulation

Can Blender be used to make 2D clothing patterns?

There is [this tutorial on how to use the shrinkwrap modifier to clothe a figurine](http://wiki.tesnexus.com/index.php/Creating_basic_clothes_in_5_minutes_using_Blender), but are there any tutorials on how one could use Blender to design dresses and other clothes in 3D and project these 3D designs onto a 2D surface (make 2D "slices") for creating and editing 2D clothing patterns in, say, Inkscape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. See ch. 7 "Creating a garment with Optitex and Blender: Constructing a Boudicca dress" of:

- Thomas Makryniotis. 2015. [*3D Fashion Design: Technique, Design and Visualization*](https://www.worldcat.org/oclc/931161503). Pavilion Books.